# First item in <ul> does not allow margin

Tags: html, css

I've been learning PHP & HTML the past few days and I've encountered a problem.

When trying to add margin to a `ul` the first item in the `ul` doesn't work.

Here's my style.css & header.php:

**Style.css:**

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #222222;
}

nav ul {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 450px;
    margin-right: 950px;
}
nav ul li {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: grey;
    float: right;
}
nav ul li a {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: grey;
}

nav ul form {
    font-size: 20px;

}
nav ul form input {
    float: left;
    border: groove;
    margin-right: 6px;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
}
nav ul form button {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 74px;
    border: 3px solid grey;
    margin-right: 20px;
    background-color: white;
    color: grey;
    font-size: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**Header.php:**

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Registratie</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <br>
            <li><a href="signup.php">Sign up</a></li>
            <br>
            <?php
                if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
                    echo "<form action='includes/logout.inc.php'>
                        <button>Log out</button>
                        </form>";
                } else {
                    echo "<form action='includes/login.inc.php' method='POST'>
                        <input type='text' name='uid' placeholder='Username'><br>
                        <input type='password' name='pwd' placeholder='Password'><br><br><br>
                        <button type='submit'>Log in</button>
                        </form>";
                }
            ?>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

[Here's an image to show what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9vfi.png)

Comment: code snippets don't support PHP, so edit your snippet to use plain html/css

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You can't have any `<br>` elements (or anything other than `<li>`) as children of a `<ul>` element

Comment: I checked it is working but in is under 'header' tag which height set '60px;' but this is 'margin-top: 450px;' this is proper way indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the best I could come up with:

```
<style>
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #222222;
}

nav ul {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 450px;
    margin-right: 950px;
}

    nav ul li {
        font-size: 25px;
        color: grey;
        /*float: right;*/
    }

        nav ul li a {
            font-family: arial;
            font-size: 20px;
            color: grey;
        }

    nav ul form {
        font-size: 20px;
    }

        nav ul form input {
            float: left;
            border: groove;
            margin-right: 6px;
            font-size: 18px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        nav ul form button {
            margin-left: 74px;
            border: 3px solid grey;
            margin-right: 20px;
            background-color: white;
            color: grey;
            font-size: 25px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

.login {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: -50px;
    text-align:center;
}
</style>

    <header>
    <nav>
        <!-- put your if statement here to create the form tag -->
        <form>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="signup.php">Sign up</a></li>
                <li class="login">
                    <input type='text' name='uid' placeholder='Username'><br>
                    <input type='password' name='pwd' placeholder='Password'><br><br><br>
                    <button type='submit'>Log in</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Except li tag you cannot have any other tag as child tag of ul tag. You need to remove br tag. And you need to create your form outside of ul tag.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is to remove `float: right;` from the `li` elements. Plus I changed and added some margins in the snippet since it would go outside the visible area otherwise. Also , I erased these invalid `br` elements inside the `ul`

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #222222;
}

nav ul {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-right: 80px;
}

nav ul li {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: grey;
  margin-left: 60px;
}

nav ul li a {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: grey;
}

nav ul form {
  font-size: 20px;
}

nav ul form input {
  float: left;
  border: groove;
  margin-right: 6px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul form button {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 74px;
  border: 3px solid grey;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  color: grey;
  font-size: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="signup.php">Sign up</a></li>
      <?php
                if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
                    echo "<form action='includes/logout.inc.php'>
                        <button>Log out</button>
                        </form>";
                } else {
                    echo "<form action='includes/login.inc.php' method='POST'>
                        <input type='text' name='uid' placeholder='Username'><br>
                        <input type='password' name='pwd' placeholder='Password'><br><br><br>
                        <button type='submit'>Log in</button>
                        </form>";
                }
            ?>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```